# iPhone Event Kit - Event Custom Field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, calendar, eventkit

I am looking to integrate Kalzuka Kal, an open course iPhone calendar into my app. It will show all the events from the official calendar app and the user will be able to add events using Event Kit.

Two things.

1. When using Event Kit can I have custom fields so of which the data is stored to the app?
2. How can I differentiate the events created in Calendar from my app? As well as that, is it possible to have events made in calendar only editable in calendar and via versa with events made in my app?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? i stuck over the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up making my own custom view and create the event programatically myself.